# python class method， Looks like the wrong syntax

Tags: python, class

Sample Code:

```
class Mysterious:
    def fake_staic():
        print('fake staic')

    def fake_sta_parameters(self):
        print(f"fake_sta_parameters {self}")



Mysterious.fake_sta_parameters("fbc")
# output fake_sta_parameters fbc
Mysterious.fake_staic()
# output fake staic
```

Please define code as follows. Why can it be executed normally? Please help me explain, thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I don't understand the question. Were you expecting it to fail? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Python doesn't have strict type enforcement, so you're allowed to try to do weird things like call a class method with a "self" that isn't actually an instance of the class.  (This can actually be useful for tests where you need to mock things out!)  If you want to protect yourself from doing weird things like this, use a type checker (e.g. `mypy`) which will warn you when you're calling a function in a way that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fake_staic():
    print('fake staic')
```

this function does not have `self` as argument and is call with class name, hence it will be treated as class method, or static method.

Whereas in second function,

```
 def fake_sta_parameters(self):
        print(f"fake_sta_parameters {self}")
```

you are providing it `self` argument, but calling it using class, and passing a value as its argument, hence `self` here is treated as argument and replaced with "fbc".
If you try calling this `fake_sta_parameters()` using object of your class, then it will give insufficient arguments error, as when a function called using object of the class, will always consider/expect function's first argument to be self reference, and hence above function will throw error as it wont have sufficient arguments to receive 'fbc' value.

Comment: *"it will be treated as class method, or static method"* -- No, class methods and static methods are not the same thing, and this is neither. It's just a function until object instantiation, at which point it would become an instance method.

Comment: No, it wont be a instance method completely unless you provide `self` as its argument

Comment: @phileinSophos No, it will be a bound method once the class is instantiated, just defined incorrectly because when called as an instance method it will expect an argument.

Comment: I think you're confusing *how an instance method is typically used* with *what it actually is*. @Mark is correct, it's defined incorrectly, but it will still be an instance method (bound method) after instantiation.

Comment: C.f. [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)